# How to initialize the shared_ptr to a structure

Tags: c++, initialization, shared-ptr

I have two definitions of structure.

```
struct ST1               
{                        
  int iVar1;               
  int iVar2;             
  float iVar3;
};

struct ST2
{
 std::shared_ptr<ST1> p_sVar4;
};

ST2 structure2;
```

I try to initialize `structure2` :

```
structure2.p_sVar4 = new ST1();
```

but that is wrong.

How to initialize `structure2`?

Comment: `structure2.p_sVar4 = make_shared<ST1>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use std::make_shared:

```
 structure2.p_sVar4 = std::make_shared<ST1>();
```

(it is generally preferred over:

```
structure2.p_sVar4 = std::shared_ptr<ST1>(new ST1)
```

)

Comment: what is the difference between `reset` and `make_shared`?

Comment: std::make_shared is more efficient and it is also good to be able to avoid raw pointers.

Comment: @user2672165 How do you pass values to the constructor?

Comment: @pooya13

`struct C
{
  C(int i) : i(i) {}
  int i;
};
auto sp = std::make_shared<C>(12);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `reset`

```
structure2.p_sVar4.reset(new ST1);
```

Comment: Is `reset` a better way than `make_shared`?

Comment: I haven't studied it deeply, but from my experience with C++, I'm guessing neither is "better".  I'm used to using reset, and it takes a pre-existing pointer, which is sometimes more versatile.